# What veggies give the best results in a mirepoix?

Tags: soup, french-cuisine

I want to make consomme. I think I have the general theory down. Im just wondering what veggies works best in the mirepoix, and in what way they should be chopped?

I wonder if the French tradition teaches something specific in this regard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean [mirepoix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirepoix)?  The standard combination is 2 parts onion to 1 part each of carrot and celery.  See that linked Wikipedia article for alternatives and the related sofrito and Cajun "holy trinity".

Answer (score 2):

If available, parsley root and parsnip work very well in addition to the classic  mix.

Also roasting a cut onion in a pan until black and adding it to the stock with the peel gives additional depth and colour